# Can Intellij community edition be configured to use JSF even though it's not supported? (using MAVEN)

Tags: validation, jsf, intellij-idea, taglib

I'm using Intelij IDEA community edition 13 and I am looking to use JSF for the first time. I'm aware that the Ultimate edition supports JSF but can the community edition can be configured manually to use JSF. If so how?

I've set up a web project with MAVEN and the Tomcat7 plugin and have included the relevant depencies as seen below in my pom.xml 

        `<dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.7</version>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <build>
        <finalName>Sample-WebApp</finalName>
          <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.3.2</version>
              <configuration>
                  <source>1.6</source>
                  <target>1.6</target>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
              <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>`

Also here is my web.xml file

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And finally, here is the head of my .xhtml file. The `xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"` and `xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"` lines are throwing me the same error. The both state the

> URI is not registered

home.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
```

I've tried fetching external resources but it's not solving the problem. It can't find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In other words, when you ignore the IDE error and just run the webapp/page, it all works fine, right?

Comment: I just found out it works fine, what is the purpose of these namespaces if it still works, is it to predicit tags?